# gonum/matrix でuse of internal package not allowedエラー

Tags: go

`gonum/matrix`を使ったソフトウェアを作ろうとしています。
しかし`github.com/gonum/matrix/mat64`をimportしようとすると以下のエラーが出てしまいコンパイルできません。

**エラー**
    `imports github.com/gonum/internal/asm: use of internal package not allowed`

これは`mat64`が`gounm`ないの`github.com/gonum/internal`パッケージをインポートしているためだと考えられます。(Go1.5からinternalパッケージというものができてそれはパッケージ内部からしか参照できないパッケージ)これを回避する方法はGolangのバージョンを1.4以下に下げるもしくはPackageの名前を変更してもらう以外に存在するのでしょうか。

**Goバージョン**
go version go1.6.3 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

依存性管理にglideを使っていたため上記のエラーが発生していたようです。
`glide up`コマンドを実行したところコンパイルできました。

Answer (score 0):

I used Google translate, so forgive me if I misunderstand.

This is an issue with internal packages, in that the import paths must stay the same. If you use `go get` and get all of the imports in the right place, it should work fine. If you wanted to fork the repository and put it somewhere else, you'd have to change all of the paths. If the goal was to fork to make a PR (thanks) you'll need to symlink the location of your forked repository into `$GOPATH/src/github.com/gonum/matrix`

Comment: Related: [英語で回答しても構いませんか？(Japanese)](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1990/15185) , [Can I ask questions in English? (English and Japanese)](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2314/15185)

Comment: In summary: answer posted in English, whether it is suited for this site or not, it has been disputed and not reached consensus.   ...I assume it is OK, though.